# Is possible to publish same app for Android TV and smartphones on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-tv

I want to use my app for Android TV and emulator (like BlueStacks). My app has Leanback Launcher request and  already published for Android TV.

When I generate signed apk, i can upload it bluestack emulator and it is running good. BlueStack emulator is shown as Samsung Galaxy S8 on Google Play

In Google Play Console, my published app only support TV devices.

Is possible to publish same app for Android TV and smartphones on Google Play?

Its my manifest file

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name=".Application.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:banner="@drawable/tv_banner"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You require TV only feature -

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
```

If you remove it, you can publish for both.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i change android:required="true" to "false" and work